# Bug with set value to <input> in JS

Tags: javascript

In Safari and Chrome I have problem with set value to input field. If you open instagram login page and call from console.

```
var username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0];
username.value = "123";
```

After this value appear in input. If I start typing in different input field, value in username field is disappears. I want to implement autofill inputs on specific site.

**Edit**

Also try it with jQuery with no success. On Coursera login [page](https://www.coursera.org/?authMode=login)

```
var jqry = document.createElement('script');
jqry.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqry);
$('input[name=email]').val("123").trigger('change');
```

Value is set, but after I start typing in password input, it reset to previous value.

---

**In Comments**

@vincent-d:

> Nothing you can do about it, it's meant to prevent xss attacks. If you
>   create a chrome module or a website that execute this command, it will
>   work. But if you just try to input it in the console, you'll just get
>   a local immediate result, then any call to the web page javascript
>   will reset everything you've done in the console

Comment: Could be great if you could give us more information

Comment: @ThanveerShah like what? Open coursera login page -> open developer console -> paste code -> you will see that email field changed -> focus on password field -> type something -> email field reset to previous state

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it. The scripts on the page store the values you input and resets them to replace anything that a script might input there. The same thing happens when you press the Login button. Goto facebook and try the same. It won't allow you to do anything.

Comment: @DEVCNN but somehow autofill from chrome works fine. How it's go around this script? Maybe we can simulate how user enter new value?

Comment: I'm using chrome and it doesn't work. Although in older browsers, this can work because they might not be supporting the security headers that prevent the client scripts from running.

Comment: Simulating user input would be through events like keyup or keypress but it isn't working. although automating this process with selenium might work as i have seen it work in some places. There are several chrome extensions which do this.

Comment: Nothing you can do about it, it's meant to prevent xss attacks. If you create a chrome module or a website that execute this command, it will work. But if you just try to input it in the console, you'll just get a local immediate result, then any call to the web page javascript will reset everything you've done in the console